# Regex sometimes returning results, and sometimes returning null on similar strings

Tags: javascript, regex, excel

I have the following example code, where there's an array of Excel formulas and I'm using regex in an attempt to isolate the URL and the Hyperlink's Title from the string. This appears to work on some, but returns `null` on others.

I thought it might be the loop, but I also get bad results as shown in Example 2 below.

**Example 1:**

```
var linkList = ['=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")', '=HYPERLINK("https://example2.com","Example 2")', '=HYPERLINK("https://example3.com","Example 3")', '=HYPERLINK("https://example4.com","Example 4")'];

const url_re = /".*?"/g;
const linkName_re = /\,(".*?")/g;

linkList.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array){
  +console.log(url_re.exec(currentValue));
  console.log(linkName_re.exec(currentValue));
  console.log("---------------------------");
});
```

**Output:**

```
[ '"https://example.com"',
  index: 11,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")' ]
[ ',"Example"',
  '"Example"',
  index: 32,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")' ]
---------------------------
[ '","',
  index: 32,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example2.com","Example 2")' ]
null
---------------------------
null
[ ',"Example 3"',
  '"Example 3"',
  index: 33,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example3.com","Example 3")' ]
---------------------------
[ '"https://example4.com"',
  index: 11,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example4.com","Example 4")' ]
null
---------------------------
```

**Example 2:**

```
const url_re = /".*?"/g;
const linkName_re = /\,(".*?")/g;

console.log(url_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")'));
console.log(linkName_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")'));
console.log("---------------------------");
console.log(url_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example2.com","Example 2")'));
console.log(linkName_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example 2")'));
console.log("---------------------------");
console.log(url_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example3.com","Example 3")'));
console.log(linkName_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example 3")'));
console.log("---------------------------");
console.log(url_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example4.com","Example 4")'));
console.log(linkName_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example 4")'));
console.log("---------------------------");
```

**Output:**

```
[ '"https://example.com"',
  index: 11,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")' ]
[ ',"Example"',
  '"Example"',
  index: 32,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")' ]
---------------------------
[ '","',
  index: 32,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example2.com","Example 2")' ]
null
---------------------------
null
[ ',"Example 3"',
  '"Example 3"',
  index: 32,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example 3")' ]
---------------------------
[ '"https://example4.com"',
  index: 11,
  input: '=HYPERLINK("https://example4.com","Example 4")' ]
null
---------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried using [regular expressions 101 tests](https://regex101.com/tests)?

Comment: @AlanLarimer I used Regex101 to test the expressions prior to posting here and they were fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to use groups in regex to match the URL and the name. something like this

```
\("(.*?)".*?\"(.*?)"
```

Complete example could be something like this

```js
var linkList = ['=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")', '=HYPERLINK("https://example2.com","Example 2")', '=HYPERLINK("https://example3.com","Example 3")', '=HYPERLINK("https://example4.com","Example 4")'];
var myRegexp = /\("(.*?)".*?\"(.*?)"/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(linkList);
while (match != null) {
  console.log(match[1])
  console.log(match[2])
  console.log("---------------------------");
  match = myRegexp.exec(linkList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `g` flag.

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

```js
const url_re = /".*?"/;
const linkName_re = /\,(".*?")/;

console.log(url_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")'));
console.log(linkName_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")'));
console.log("---------------------------");
console.log(url_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example2.com","Example 2")'));
console.log(linkName_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example 2")'));
console.log("---------------------------");
console.log(url_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example3.com","Example 3")'));
console.log(linkName_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example 3")'));
console.log("---------------------------");
console.log(url_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example4.com","Example 4")'));
console.log(linkName_re.exec('=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example 4")'));
console.log("---------------------------");
```